# How to keep track of different types of missing values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

## Summary

It's important in many scientific applications to keep track of different kinds of missing value. Is a value for 'weekly income from main job' missing because the person doesn't have a job, or because they have a job but refused to answer?

- Storing all missing values as `NA` or `NaN` loses this information.
- Storing missing value labels (e.g., 'missing because no job', 'missing because refused to answer') in a **separate column** means the researcher must keep track of two columns for every operation she performs – such as groupby, renaming, and so on. This creates endless opportunities for mistakes and errors.
- Storing missing value labels within the **same column** (e.g., as negative numbers, as in the example below, or very large numbers like 99999)  means the researcher must manually keep track of how missing value labels are encoded for every column, and creates many other opportunities for mistakes (e.g., forgetting that a column includes missing values and taking a raw mean instead of using the correct mask).

It is very easy to handle this problem in `Stata` (see below), by using a data type that stores both numeric values and missing value labels, and with functions that know how to handle this data type. This is highly **performant** (data type remains numeric, not string or mixed – think of NumPy's data types, except instead of having just `NaN` we have `NaN1`, `NaN2`, etc.) What is the best way of achieving something like this in pandas?

Note: I'm an economist, but this is also an incredibly common workflow for political scientists, epidemiologists, etc. – anyone who deals with survey data. In this context, the analyst knows what the missing values are via a codebook, really cares about keeping track of them, and has hundreds or thousands of columns to deal with – so, indeed, needs an automated way of keeping track of them.

## Motivation/context

It's extremely common when dealing with any kind of survey data to have multiple kinds of missing data.

Here is a minimal example from a government questionnaire used to produce official employment statistics:

- [Q1] Do you have a job?
- [Q2] [If Q1=Yes] What is your weekly income from that job?

The above occurs in pretty much every government-run labor force survey in the world (e.g., the [UK Labour Force Survey](https://www.ons.gov.uk/file?uri=/employmentandlabourmarket/peopleinwork/employmentandemployeetypes/methodologies/labourforcesurveyuserguidance/lfsvolume2jm18.pdf), the US Current Population Survey, etc.).

Now, for a given respondent, if [Q2] is missing, it could be that (1) they answered No to [Q1], and so were **ineligible** to be asked [Q2], or that (2) they answered Yes to [Q1] but **refused** to answer [Q2] (perhaps because they were embarrassed at how much/little they earn, or because they didn't know).

As a researcher, it matters a great deal to me whether it was (1) that occurred, or whether it was (2). Suppose my job is to report the average weekly income of workers in the United States. If there are many missing values for this [Q2] column, but they are all labeled 'missing because respondent answered no to [Q1]', then I can take the average of [Q2] with confidence – it is, indeed, the average weekly income of people in work. (All the missing values are people who didn't have a job.)

On the other hand, if those [Q2] missing values are all labeled 'missing because respondent was asked this question but refused to answer', then I cannot simply report the average of [Q2] as the average weekly income of workers. I'll need to issue caveats around my results. I'll need to analyze the kinds of people who don't answer (are they missing at random, or are people in higher-income occupations more likely to refuse, for example, biasing my results?). Possibly I'll try to impute missing values, and so on.

### The problem

Because these 'reasons for being missing' are so important, government statistical agencies will code the different reasons within the column:

[image]

So the column containing the answers to [Q2] above might contain the values [1500, -8, 10000, -2, 3000, -1, 6400].

In this case, '1500', '10000', and so on are 'true' answers to [Q2] ($1,500 weekly income, $10,000 weekly income, etc.); whereas '-8' means they weren't eligible to answer (because they answered No to [Q1]) '-2' means they were eligible to answer but refused to do so, and so on.

Now, obviously, if I take the average of this column, I'm going to get something meaningless.

On the other hand, if I just replace all negative values with `NaN`, then I can take the average – but I've lost all this valuable information about why values are missing. For example, I may want to have a function that takes any column and reports, for that column, statistics like the mean and median, the number of **eligible** observations (i.e., everything except value=-8), and the percent of *those* that were non-missing.

### It works great in Stata

Doing this in `Stata` is extremely easy. `Stata` has 27 numeric missing categories: '.a' to '.z'. (More details [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/faq/how-can-i-recode-missing-values-into-different-categories/).) I can write:

`replace weekly_income = .a if weekly_income == -1
 replace weekly_income = .b if weekly_income == -8`

and so on.

Then (in pseudocode) I can write

`stats weekly_income if weekly_income!=.b`

When reporting the mean, `Stata` will automatically ignore the values coded as missing (indeed, they're now not numeric); but it will also give me **missing value statistics** only for the observations I care about (in this case, those eligible to be asked the question, i.e., those who weren't originally coded '-8').

## What is the best way to handle this in Pandas?

Setup:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({
        'income': [1500, -8, 10000, -2, 3000, -1, 6400]})
```

Desired outcome:

```
>>> df.income.missing_dict = {'-1': ['.a', 'Don\'t know'], '-2': ['.b', 'Refused']} # etc.
>>> df
  income
0       1500
1  Inapplic.
2      10000
3    Refused
4       3000
5 Don't know
6       6400

>>> assert df.income.mean() == np.mean([1500, 10000, 3000, 6400])
(passes)
```

### The 'obvious' workaround

Clearly, one option is to split every column into two columns: one numeric column with non-missing values and NaNs, and the other a categorical column with categories for the different types of missing value.

But this is extremely inconvenient. These surveys often have thousands of columns, and a researcher might well use hundreds in certain kinds of economic analysis. Having two columns for every 'underlying' column means the researcher has to keep track of two columns for every operation she performs – such as groupby, renaming, and so on. This creates endless opportunities for mistakes and errors. It also means that displaying the table is very wasteful – for any column, I need to now display *two* columns, one of which for any given observation is always redundant. (This is wasteful both of screen real estate, and of the human analysts' attention, having to identify which two columns are a 'pair'.)

### Other ideas

Two other thoughts that occur to me, both probably non-ideal:

(1) Create a new data type in pandas that works similarly to Stata (i.e., adds '.a', '.b', etc. to allowable values for numeric columns).

(2) Use the two-columns solution above, but (re)write 'wrapper' functions in pandas so that 'groupby' etc. keeps track of the pairs of columns for me.

I suspect that (1) is the best solution for the long term, but it would presumably require a huge amount of development.

On the other hand, maybe there are already packages that solve this? Or people have better work-arounds?

Comment: You've given a lot of detail, but you haven't provided a sample dataframe and a desired output.  If you're asking for a subjective opinion on how to deal with missing data in general, it's probably too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: If you Google the phrase "PANDAS impute missing data", you’ll find references that can explain it much better than we can in an answer here.

Comment: @user3483203 I've added a sample dataframe and a desired output.

Comment: @Prune This is NOT about imputing missing data. I've gone to a lot of effort to explain exactly what the issue is. This is a problem faced by many many people, and I think the lack of an obvious solution is what keeps many people stuck in proprietary software like Stata and unable to switch to pandas. If you think an answer to my question is easily findable, I've be very grateful for a link!

Comment: I don't really see the issue. The invalid place-holders were all chosen to be negative numbers for a reason; any 'real' answer to those questions must have a value `>=0`. So if you want an average of the real answers you just need a simple mask `df.loc[df.col_name >= 0, col_name].mean()`

Comment: And you can add more sophisticated logic if you want, like the value `>= 0` and the answer to the other question was `!= -8` or whatever you want to select the relevant subset.

Comment: @mww: Thanks; I see my error; I don't yet quite understand the problem.  The lack of masks (per `Aloliz`'s comments) let me leap to the wrong conclusions (my error).  Masking out unwanted values is a typical technique; can you explain a bit what drawbacks that leaves in your data-handling system?

Comment: @ALollz I agree your code is a way of taking the 'correct' mean. But it requires the researcher to manually keep track of how missing values are encoded for every column. Sometimes, in the same survey(!), negative values will be used for some missing values and '999' will be used for others. Sometimes columns have 'real' negative values (e.g., standard deviations above/below the mean), and one would still like to keep track of missing values in that case. I'm asking for a general solution. Other software packages have a very elegant general solution, as in the example I gave of Stata.

Comment: @Prune does my answer to ```ALollz``` above address your question?

Comment: That's a good summary; thanks.  Also, thanks for the personal tag -- I'd missed retracting my closure vote.  I also reversed my down-vote (to up).  Now to cogitate -- my experience is mainly in cleansing data sets through pre-processing.  For instance, you can run simple detection algorithms to find clustered outliers, such as that camp of `999` values in a column that otherwise ranges 0-150.  Such an algorithm *should* be able to alter all of your missing values to a common value, that you can then ignore with a single condition.  Is that something that might work for you?

Comment: I see your point, but there just isn't a perfect solution. You could easily replace dummy values with human readable words using `Series.replace`, but then every column is now an object, which isn't very performant, and now all of the built in pandas functions like .mean() won't work without manipulation. You need to constantly subset your `DataFrame` to only the numeric rows (which you would have done with the mask previously anyway). It's inconvenient, but I'd think the categorical column is going to be the cleanest solution given some columns are positive, others are negative

Comment: @Prune Thanks! :) That solution sounds great for many cases, although in my case I know in advance what all the '-1, '-2', '999' etc. are (they are listed in the codebook that came with the survey) and I want to keep track of them for the reasons given in the question. Are you suggesting a version of the two-column approach? Or a version of the one-column approach where you keep track elsewhere of which values are missing in a way that can be called with a single condition? (What would be the best way of doing that?)

Comment: @ALollz Thanks – if there is no elegant way of handling this in pandas currently, that in itself is good to know.

Comment: Both – I want to re-emphasize that in the context I'm thinking about (I'm an economist, but this is also an incredibly common workflow for political scientists, epidemiologists, etc. – anyone who deals with survey data), the analyst knows what the missing values are via a codebook, really cares about keeping track of them (ideally, having the system keep track of them for her), and has hundreds or thousands of columns to deal with – so, indeed, *needs* an automated way of keeping track of them.

Comment: I wouldn't say `pandas` can't handle it. The STATA code you provided can be done  exactly the same way in pandas. `df['weekly_income'] = df.weekly_income.replace(-8, 'b')` and then you could do `df.loc[df.weekly_income != ''b', 'weekly_income'].mean()` I just don't see an easy way around needing all of this extra information though, since it's imperative to performing your calculation correctly.

Comment: @ALollz Right, your solution works, but as you noted originally, "every column is now an object, which isn't very performant, and now all of the built in pandas functions like .mean() won't work without manipulation." Other packages recognize that missing data is so common that it should be handled by things like .mean() automatically. Indeed, Numpy does, but it only lets you have one type of missing value (NaN); Stata lets you keep a numeric data type but have many more types of missing value.

Comment: Do you need to have the `missing_dict` in that particular format?  You've changed the values from `int` to `str` and stuffed the choice and interpretation together into a list.

Comment: @Prune Thanks very much for your answer! No, the `missing_dict` does not have to be that form at all – what would you recommend as a cleaner way? (I guess with your solution, one doesn't need '.a' or '.b' at all any more, for a start – although it would be nice to have a quick way to refer to the different kinds of missing values)

Comment: Oh sorry, I see what you mean now – just changing '-1' (str) to -1 (int) in the dict.

Answer (score 1):

To show the solution, I'm taking the liberty of changing the `missing_dict` keys to match the data type of `income`.

```
>>> df
   income
0    1500
1      -8
2   10000
3      -2
4    3000
5      -1
6    6400
>>> df.income.missing_dict
{-8: ['.c', 'Stifled by companion'], -2: ['.b', 'Refused'], -1: ['.a', "Don't know"]}
```

Now, here's how to filter the rows according to the values being in the "missing" list:

```
>>> df[(~df.income.isin((df.income.missing_dict)))]
   income
0    1500
2   10000
4    3000
6    6400
```

Note the extra parentheses around the filter values: we have to pass a `tuple` of values to `isin`.  Then apply the *tilde* operator, bit-wise negation, to get a series of Booleans.

Finally, apply `mean` to the resulting data column:

```
>>> df[(~df.income.isin((df.income.missing_dict)))].mean()
income    5225.0
dtype: float64
```

Does that toss you in the right direction?  From here, you can simply replace `income` with the appropriate column or variable name as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas recently introduced a custom array type called [`ExtensionArray`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.api.extensions.ExtensionArray.html) that allows defining what is in essence a custom column type, allowing you to (sort of) use actual values alongside missing data without dealing with two columns. Here is a very, very crude implementation, which has barely been tested:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.arrays.base import ExtensionArray


class StataData(ExtensionArray):
    def __init__(
        self, data, missing=None, factors=None, dtype=None, copy=False
    ):
        def own(array, dtype=dtype):
            array = np.asarray(array, dtype)
            if copy:
                array = array.copy()
            return array

        self.data = own(data)

        if missing is None:
            missing = np.zeros_like(data, dtype=int)
        else:
            missing = own(missing, dtype=int)
        self.missing = missing

        self.factors = own(factors)

    @classmethod
    def _from_sequence(cls, scalars, dtype=None, copy=False):
        return cls(scalars, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)

    @classmethod
    def _from_factorized(cls, data, original):
        return cls(original, None, data)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return type(self)(
            self.data[key], self.missing[key], self.factors
        )

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.data[key] = value
        self.missing[key] = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.data)

    @property
    def dtype(self):
        return self.data.dtype

    @property
    def shape(self):
        return self.data.shape

    @property
    def nbytes(self):
        return self.data.nbytes + self.missing.nbytes + self.factors.nbytes

    def view(self):
        return self

    @property
    def reason_missing(self):
        return self.missing

    def isna(self):
        return self.missing != 0

    def __repr__(self):
        s = {}
        for attr in ['data', 'missing', 'factors']:
            s[attr] = getattr(self, attr)
        return repr(s)
```

With this implementation, you can do the following:

```
>>> a = StataData([1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 0, 1, 0])
>>> s = pd.Series(a)
>>> print(s[s.isna()])
2    3
dtype: int32
>>> print(s[~s.isna()])
0    1
1    2
3    4
dtype: int32
>>> print(s.isna().values.reason_missing)
array([1])
```

Hopefully someone who understands this API can chime in and help improve this. For starters, `a` cannot be used in `DataFrames`, only `Series`.

```
>>> print(pd.DataFrame({'a': s}).isna())
0  False
1  False
2  False
3  False
```